# inversify: how to bind Model<Document> to container object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I am developing an application using typescript, mean stack, inversify-express-utils and inversifyjs as my IOC container.  I am receiving an error for my entries in the inversify.config.ts file for the entry that add a Model to the container.  For example,

inversify.config.ts:

```
container.bind<Model<Document>>(TYPES.Document).to(User).whenTargetNamed("userSchema");
```

This seems to result in the following error:
"Argument of type Model is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => Model'.  Type 'IUserModel' is not assignable type 'Model'.  Property 'findByid' is missing in type 'IUserModel'."

igroupmodel.ts:

```
export interface IUserModel extends IUser, Document
```

types.ts:

```
Document: Symbol("Model")
```

group.js(last line):

```
export let User = mongoose.model<IUserModel>("User", UserSchema);
```

What is the correct way to inject a mongoose model into the container?  I have been looking for an example demonstrating how to work with inversifyjs and mongoose and have not found a solution.

Update:
When I substitute to(User) with toConstantValue(User) I am no longer getting the error.  However, my log file seems to display the following error in my log files:

> "Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier:
>   Model"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an example of mongoose + inversify [here](https://github.com/stelltec/public-tech-demos/tree/master/nodejs-madrid-meetup/demo3). The example uses the [onion architecture](https://dzone.com/articles/onion-architecture-is-interesting) but you should be able to use a different architecture if you don't like it...